# Flutter file_picker plugin can't build project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, filepicker

After adding   file_picker: ^1.13.3 to my dependencies the project can't build with this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@7dfb72cd' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

but each time i remove it the project builds successfully, please help out i have tried various versions suggested but all to no avail

Here is the android manifest as requested

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.www.app">
   <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="finosellapp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
          
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
          
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Show me android>app>source>main>Android Manifest.xml

Comment: @AmonChowdhury i have updated the questions with Android Manifest,Kindly recheck thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because file_picker currently doesn't support scoped storage, you'll need to set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on your AndroidManifest.xml file, under :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.www.app">
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="finosellapp"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
       
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
                />

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: If it works then please set it as a correct answer. It will help other developers too.

Comment: What's you issue? @LizardKing_96

Comment: The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin file_picker...

Comment: I followed the instructions given by the issues page and it did not help. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

Comment: That could be another case. There are different settings when you use AndroidX and when not. Ask a question and comment here I will try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this one to your Android Manifest file

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

And Change app `compileSdkVersion` to 28 in filepicker `build.gradle` file. To get this file you requested to open `MainActivity.class` file in andriod folder at right corner Open for Editing android studio click on that it open as new android project. then select file filepicker `build.gradle` file.

Hope this will help to you.

[image: File Name like this.]

I struggle with this issue past 5days, now only I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

ADD:
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml

ADD:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3' in your android -> build.gradle

```
ebuildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    }
}
```

ADD:
`distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`
in your gradle-wrapper.properties

Create a file 'proguard-rules.pro' and write:
`-keep class androidx.lifecycle.** { *; }`

In your android -> app -> build.gradle add:

```
android{
    buildTypes {
       release{
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
}
```

``